# I want this menu to be selective by mouse

Tags: assembly, mouse

I have this menu:

```
data segment
    menu db "Please select a choice:" 
         db "1. J",13,10
         db "2. C",13,10
         db "3. G",13,10 
         db "4. T" ,13,10  
         db "5. C",13,10      
         db "6. E",13,10,'$

ends
```

I want the user to be able to click on one of these options (1-6) using a mouse. For example I take the mouse and click on "1. J" and after clicking I ask for input.

I'm stuck on the part of using a mouse to click.

I can't think of a way to structure this reasoning.

Comment: What architecture?  16-bit x86 with DOS?  In text mode?  What interface are you using to get mouse click information?

Comment: It looks like a textmode in DOS.  Read column and row of mouse cursor when the mouse button was released and compare those coordinates with your menu. Look at [interrupt 33h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-5962.htm).

Comment: You're also going to want to make sure that your mouse doesn't initially spawn over top of the menu. If I recall correctly, when the mouse is shown using `int 33h`, any graphics on screen under it will be destroyed, but once it's visible it stops "eating away" at whatever is underneath. To fix this I move it off screen, show the mouse, then move it back to center screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something similar, and here's my idea. Since each menu choice has four characters (not counting the newlines), you can describe an imaginatry rectangle (you don't need to actually draw this rectangle on screen) that's as wide as 4 characters and as tall as 6 characters, using a set of coordinates that are relative to wherever you printed the menu, then read the mouse information to see if the following is true:

- The left mouse button is held down, AND
- The cursor's row and column values fall within the rectangle coordinates.

As an example here's an idea on how you might figure out if the mouse cursor is in the rectangle:

```
CompareMouseToBoundingBox:
;in: cx = column mouse is in, dx = row mouse is in.
cmp cx,[rectangleX1]  ;some address in memory where you stored the rectangle coords
jb notInBounds

cmp cx,[rectangleX2]
ja notInBounds

cmp dx,[rectangleY1]
jb notInBounds

cmp dx,[rectangleY2]
jbe notInbounds
   ;in bounds
   mov al,0FFh   ;we'll consider this value to be "true"
   ret

notInBounds:
mov al,0         ;we'll consider this value to be "false"
ret
```

There are a few different ways to read the mouse, the naive approach is just reading the current button state, but that can cause logic errors if (for example) the user clicks and holds the mouse button when not over the menu, then drags it to the menu. That may not be the desired behavior all the time. [int 33h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-5961.htm) with `ah = 05h` might help you with that.